# Android & Firestore - deducting value from an object

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

General context: The app I'm making manages activities with resources at hand. Once users create *cases*, the amount of materials each case needs is deducted from the inventory of materials.

What I'm trying to do: I've saved the materials on *Firestore* and would like to deduct the quantity of the material used up by a case from the saved quantity. Here's the model class:

```
data class Material(
var type: String = "",
var material: String = "",
var size: String = "",
var description: String = "",
var unit: String = "",
var quantity: String = "0",
var actualquantity: String = "0"        /*actual is the confirmed quantity*/) :FireStoreData()
```

My attempt: I've tried to save the list of materials needed for a case, *exitingMaterials*, and search each of them in the database, then merge them to a new *Material* object that has the updated quantity, as follows:

```
//region DEDUCTION: DIFFERENT APPROACH
    for (Material material : exitingMaterials) {
        db.collection("materials")
                .whereEqualTo("type", material.getType())
                .whereEqualTo("material", material.getMaterial())
                .whereEqualTo("description", material.getDescription())
                .whereEqualTo("size", material.getSize())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Material currentMaterial = document.toObject(Material.class);
                                try {
                                    db.collection("materials").document(document.getId()).set(
                                            new Material(
                                                    material.getType(),
                                                    material.getMaterial(),
                                                    material.getSize(),
                                                    material.getDescription(),
                                                    material.getUnit(),
                                                    ("" + (Integer.parseInt(currentMaterial.getQuantity()) - Integer.parseInt(material.getQuantity()))),
                                                    material.getActualquantity()
                                            ), SetOptions.merge()
                                    );
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't subtract", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Task Unsuccessful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    //end region
```

However, I'm not getting any feedback from the app. The task says deduction is successful, but the firestore data remains unchanged. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check first the value of `material` and `currentMaterial` ?

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales I set a breakpoint on the line where I declare the currentMaterial. The breakpoint could not be reached, and now the toast indicating success doesn't display.

Comment: Can you add the complete and error listener to the internal query e-g you are setting the material object so there might you get soemthing related to that query

Comment: That's mean they where condition you are putting either could not found the document which you want to update that might the reason that your breakpoint doesn't trigger because it could not go to onComplete function. Just try with one where condition then do with other where and find out which is breaking the case

Comment: Check the snapshot if has children

Comment: I added a success and failure method to the _set_ method. Neither were displayed. The reason I think this is interesting is because there was a previous way of doing things. I get all the data from the db, perform the deduction operation locally, and update the data. It works. But as operations go on, bugs appear and code becomes cumbersome.